# How to stop those mods from downloading when connecting to a server in Call of Duty 4?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

When we try to connect to a server in Call of Duty 4 Modern Warfare, we sometimes start downloading mods. These can take a lot of time if the mods are bulky. I would rather connect to a different server than wait for these mods to download. How can I stop those mods from downloading and return to the console again? No keys seem to work: esc, contrl+Q etc.

Only thing that seems to work is end process of the game and then start it again. Once when I did this it messed up my settings so the next time the game wouldn't start. Is there an easy way to stop trying to stop mods from downloading so you can then connect to a different server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Enable console. Whenever you want to abort a connection, open up console by pressing the tilde (`) key, (left to 1 on the keyboard) and type:

```
/disconnect
```

Remember to include the backslash. It'll immediately terminate the connection, no matter where you are.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach to this is to avoid modded servers altogether.

You'll know that it is a modded server if you look at the IW column (it should appear between the green check and PB columns).  If it doesn't have an `X` next to it, it is a modded server and connecting to it will likely cause you to download the mods and maps.  If it does have an `X`, it's a "pure" server (using IW's settings) and you shouldn't have to download anything more.

Otherwise if you unknowingly connect to a modded server, you could disconnect from it as Howard suggested.  Though I'd recommend binding this command to a key.  Personally, I have it bound to <kbd>F8</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no way to cancel a download during a connection response.  As you mentioned the only way is to force terminate the process and restart the game.  (which can lead to settings problems)

Comment: I'll wait for some time to see if anyone else can provide a different method. Else I guess this is it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cl_allowDownload "0"` cvar to disable automatic downloading of extra server entities. Some servers may have extras which are not necessary, but if it's a fully-fledged mod (a la Promod) you'll need to get the files.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could also unauthorize any download when connecting to a server. This means custom maps and mods. If you do this and try to connect a mod server, Call of Duty will warn you that you can't connect to the server because you miss some files.

**How to unauthorize downloads:**
Go to `Options`->`Multiplayer options...` and set `Allow downloading` to `No`.